# Hemitian operator inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I am trying to find two Hermitian operators $A$ and $B$ (whose representations are $2 \times 2$ complex matrices) for which neither $A \leq B$ nor $A \geq B $ holds.

Note that $A \geq B$ iff $\langle(A-B)x, x \rangle\geq 0$ where $\langle~{,}~\rangle$ is an inner product.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: 
$$ A = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
\end{array}\right) $$
$$ B = \left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another example: $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0},\ B=0$. Both $A-B$ and $B-A$ are indefinite.